# Differences between anti-bioterrorism organizations in the resident evil universe

Tags: video-games, zombie, resident-evil

What is the difference between the anti-bioterrorism organizations in the resident evil universe [BSA,D.S.O,TerraSave]?

Answer (score 3):

[Bioterrorism Security Assessment Alliance](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Bioterrorism_Security_Assessment_Alliance) (BSAA) are a United Nations backed combat group who's main purpose is to prevent, and exterminate bio-terrorism.

[Division of Security Operations](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Division_of_Security_Operations) (DSO) are similar to the BSAA but are under the direct jurisdiction of the US government.

[TerraSave](http://residentevil.wikia.com/TerraSave) are primarily a human rights organization.

There's loads of info about each on their respective wiki entries, no point in copying and pasting it all here.

Comment: So is bsaa not under usa jurisdiction? Whos higher up/got more power?

Comment: It would depend where an operation as taking place. If it was in the US, the DSO would be in charge. Pretty much [anywhere](http://www.un.org/en/members/) outside the US would be the BSAA.

Comment: So in theory you could be in more than one Organization ?

Comment: You could probably be in TerraSave and one of the other two, but I doubt you could be in both the DSO and the BSAA at the same time. Their roles are too similar, it would be a conflict of interests. If a crisis was declared in the US and both groups were mobilised, which would you go with? Someone could be a member of all three somewhere in canon, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Could someone in theory be part of the two organisations as a liaison officer?

Comment: @LiamBrown I'm sorry, I'm afraid I don't know enough about inter-agency politics to give you any sort of answer fro that.